# Send HTTP request from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have a proxy app that stops HTTP requests upon meeting certain conditions. Then a warning HTML page is shown to the user, with a button that allows the user to proceed with the original request. So far I've been caching the original requests at backend and using a call to the backend to resend them. I'd like to make it more stateless by storing the original request in the HTML warning page itself and sending it from there. Presumably using JavaScript.

I'm looking for a good way to create an HTTP request object from the header and body string and sending it. Is there some good JavaScript library to do this easily?

This is how I imagine it - pseudocode to show the idea:

```
<body>
    Do you want to proceed?
    <input type="button" value="Proceed" onclick="proceed();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let header = 
            'POST https://host.com HTTP/1.1' +
            'Host: host.com' +
            ...;

        let body = 'param1=value1';

        function proceed() {
            let response = sendRequest(header, body);
            replacePageContent(response);
        }

        function sendRequest(header, body) {
            let httpRequest = new HttpRequest(header, body); // which JS library can do that?
            httpRequest.send();
        }

        function replacePageContent(response) {
            // how do I replace the page content with the response?
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What you are describing is known as **ajax**. No libraries needed if you use native `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest` although wrappers for these add additional functionality/error handing

Comment: I guess I could use fetch(). It allows setting the body with a string. I would still need to parse and build the header manually. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Also, when using fetch(), there is a lot of problems with the security headers, like same origin policy, cors etc. I might just stick with the original solution - sending the requests from backend.